# Binding to an UserControl's property in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a simple data template in an UserControl composed of a `TextBlock` and two buttons. The `DataContext` is set to a list of objects. One button and the TextBlock are bound to properties of that object, but I need one button to be bound to a property of the UserControl.

**Can I use `RelativeSource` to try and find the UC's class, and get the property that way?** Something like this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControlClass}}, Path=SomeProperty}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the UserControl give it:

```
x:Name="MyUserControl"
```

Then to access the property you can simply use:

```
"{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=SomeProperty}"
```

Comment: I'm ashamed I didn't think of this. Thanks.